# Advanced custom fields remove duplicate values

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm using ACF to create a teams member section that will be filtered by job title. I have everything working as I want except if 2 people have the same job title then it shows 2 of the same job title in the filter but I only want it to show 1 of any job title.

Below is my ACF field:

```
<?php if( have_rows('team') ): ?>

    <div class="filters">

       <div class="filter" data-filter="all">Show All</div>

         <?php while( have_rows('team') ): the_row(); ?>

           <div class="filter" data-filter=".<?php echo get_sub_field('job_title'); ?>"><?php echo get_sub_field('job_title'); ?></div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

</div>

  <div id="Container">

     <?php while( have_rows('team') ): the_row(); ?>

        <div class="mix <?php echo get_sub_field('job_title'); ?>" data-myorder="2"><?php echo get_sub_field('name'); ?></div>

        <?php endwhile; ?>

         </div>
```

Is there a way to remove duplicate values for the filter?

Comment: Your info architecture seems wrong. Create a job title taxonomy, link it to the team member post-type and then create your filter list from the taxonomy rather than by scanning your printed content.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the loop to push objects to an array, then use array_unique to only return unique entries!

http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_push.asp

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php